# curve_fit with ODE of unknown coefficients

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, ode

I'm trying to solve the equation Iy'' + b|y'|y' + ky = 0 and fit the coefficients to data.

This is the code I have so far (ready to run):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Define derivatives of function
def f(y, t, I, b, k):
    theta, omega = y
    derivs = [omega, -b / I * omega * abs(omega) - k / I * theta]
    return derivs

# integrate the function
def yint(t, I, b, k, y0, y1):
    y = odeint(f, [y0, y1], t, args=(I, b, k))
    return y.ravel()

# define t and y to fit
y0 = [.5, 0]
t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
y = np.cos(t)*np.e**(-.01*t)

# fit
vals, cov = curve_fit(yint, t, y, p0=[0.002245, 1e-5, 0.2492, y0[0], y[1]])
```

However, when I run the function, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "---", line 24, in <module>
    vals, cov = curve_fit(yint, t, y, p0=[0.002245, 1e-5, 0.2492, y0[0], y[1]])
  File "---.py", line 578, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kw)
  File "---.py", line 371, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
  File "---.py", line 20, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "---.py", line 447, in _general_function
    return function(xdata, *params) - ydata
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (600,) (300,)
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that function yint returns an array of shape (600,) for the argument of shape (300,). Think again about `yint`: it solves a second-order differential equation by representing it as a system of two first-order equations. So the result of `y = odeint(...)` has two columns, one for the solution itself, the second for its derivative. Its shape is (300,2).  Mashing the solution and its derivative together with `ravel` does not make sense. Instead, you should only take the actual solution, that's the thing you are fitting.

So, replace

```
   return y.ravel()
```

with

```
   return y[:, 0]
```